# How to Shutdown Rserve(), running in DEBUG

Tags: r, debugging, shutdown, rserve

I have started Rserve() from within RStudio on my Mac in debug mode with the following:

```
Rserve(debug=TRUE,args="--no-save")
```

And as a result, I get the message:

```
Note: debug version of Rserve doesn't daemonize so your R session will be blocked until you shut down Rserve.
```

This is fine & good, until I've finished with using Rserve in debug mode.

How can I send an interrupt in order to gracefully shutdown Rserve() ?

Thanks!

Comment: What OS? `Esc` often does the trick on Windows. `ctrl-c` on *nix or Mac.

Comment: This was mentioned on a Mac.  When I start Rserve() within RStudio using the command `Rserve(debug=TRUE,args="--no-save")`, then it is no longer possible to send more commands into the console window.  They each wait (queue) until after the console is returned from debug.