# How can I shut down Rserve gracefully?

Tags: r, rserve

I have tried many options both in Mac and in Ubuntu.
I read the Rserve documentation

```
http://rforge.net/Rserve/doc.html
```

and that for the Rserve and RSclient packages:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSclient/RSclient.pdf

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rserve/Rserve.pdf

I cannot figure out what is the correct workflow for opening/closing a connection within Rserve and for shutting down Rserve 'gracefully'.

For example, in Ubuntu, I installed R from source with the ./config --enable-R-shlib (following the Rserve documentation) and also added the 'control enable' line in /etc/Rserve.conf.

In an Ubuntu terminal:

```
library(Rserve)
library(RSclient)
Rserve()
c<-RS.connect()
c ## this is an Rserve QAP1 connection

## Trying to shutdown the server
RSshutdown(c) 
Error in writeBin(as.integer....): invalid connection

RS.server.shutdown(c)
Error in RS.server.shutdown(c): command failed with satus code 0x4e: no control line present   (control commands disabled or server shutdown)
```

I can, however, CLOSE the connection:

```
RS.close(c)
>NULL
c ## Closed Rserve connection
```

After closing the connection, I also tried the options (also tried with argument 'c', even though the connection is closed):

```
RS.server.shutdown()
RSshutdown()
```

So, my questions are:

1- How can I close Rserve gracefully?

2- Can Rserve be used without RSclient?

I also looked at

[How to Shutdown Rserve(), running in DEBUG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004257/how-to-shutdown-rserve-running-in-debug)

but the question refers to the debug mode and is also unresolved. (I don't have enough reputation to comment/ask whether the shutdown works in the non-debug mode).

Also looked at:

[how to connect to Rserve with an R client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314880/how-to-connect-to-rserve-with-an-r-client)

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Load Rserve and RSclient packages, then connect to the instances.

```
> library(Rserve)
> library(RSclient)

> Rserve(port = 6311, debug = FALSE)
> Rserve(port = 6312, debug = TRUE)

Starting Rserve...
 "C:\..\Rserve.exe" --RS-port 6311
Starting Rserve...
 "C:\..\Rserve_d.exe" --RS-port 6312 

> rsc <- RSconnect(port = 6311)
> rscd <- RSconnect(port = 6312)
```

Looks like they're running...

```
> system('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Rserve.exe"')
> system('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Rserve_d.exe"')

Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
Rserve.exe                    8600 Console                    1     39,312 K
Rserve_d.exe                 12652 Console                    1     39,324 K
```

Let's shut 'em down.

```
> RSshutdown(rsc)
> RSshutdown(rscd)
```

And they're gone...

```
> system('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Rserve.exe"')
> system('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Rserve_d.exe"')

INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.
```

Rserve can be used w/o RSclient by starting it with args and/or a config script. Then you can connect to it from some other program (like Tableau) or with your own code. RSclient provides a way to pass commands/data to Rserve from an instance of R.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you! So, if I understand correctly, in order to connect an R process with an Rserve instance, I have to use RSclient, correct? I also needed to specify the “args” command in Rserve (otherwise I get a fatal error) and when using the debug=TRUE, the command line keeps waiting and it ends with "Error: Unable to establish connection with R session". So, using a mac, only the debug=F option seems to work and I used system('ps aux | grep Rserve') [this opens 2 connections, with two different IDs..]. Thank you so much!!

Comment: This works great for Rserve(port = 6311, debug = FALSE,args="--no-save"). Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

On a Windows system, if you want to close an `RServe` instance, you can use the `system` function in `R` to close it down.
For example in `R`:

```
library(Rserve)
Rserve() # run without any arguments or ports specified
system('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Rserve.exe"') # run this to see RServe instances and their PIDs
system('TASKKILL /PID {yourPID} /F') # run this to kill off the RServe instance with your selected PID
```

If you have closed your RServe instance with that PID correctly, the following message will appear:

> SUCCESS: The process with PID xxxx has been terminated.

You can check the RServe instance has been closed down by entering

`system('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Rserve.exe"')`

again. If there are no RServe instances running any more, you will get the message

> INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.

More help and info on this topic can be seen in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066588/rserve-server-how-to-terminate-a-blocking-instance-eval-taking-forever?rq=1).

Note that the 'RSClient' approach mentioned in an earlier answer is tidier and easier than this one, but I put it forward anyway for those who start `RServe` without knowing how to stop it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not able to shut it down within R, run the codes below to kill it in terminal. These codes work on Mac.

```
$ ps ax | grep Rserve  # get active Rserve sessions
```

You will see outputs like below. 29155 is job id of the active Rserve session.

```
29155  /Users/userid/Library/R/3.5/library/Rserve/libs/Rserve

38562  0:00.00 grep Rserve
```

Then run

```
$ kill 29155
```